# Can I change .gif file to be a bitmap using Glide?

Tags: android, bitmap, gif

Can I change .gif file to be a bitmap using Glide ?

I'm try to load gif to bitmap but it show static picture.

```
Glide.with(context)
            .asBitmap()
            .load(R.drawable.image)
            .into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
                override fun onResourceReady(bitmap: Bitmap,transition: Transition<in Bitmap>?) {
                    remoteViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.testImage, bitmap)
                    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, remoteViews)
                }

                override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
                    // this is called when
                    // imageView is cleared on lifecycle call or for
                    // some other reason.
                    // if you are referencing the bitmap somewhere else too other than this imageView
                    // clear it here as you can no longer have the bitmap
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is not correct you are using `asBitmap()` in the Glide . You should use `asGif()` instead of `asBitmap()`.

**For Example-**

```
Glide.with(itemView.getContext())    
    .asGif()
    .load(thumbPath)                             
    .placeholder(ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(context.getResources(), 
                     R.drawable.image_loading_placeholder, null))
    .centerCrop()
    .into(new ImageViewTarget<GifDrawable>(imageView) {
         @Override
         protected void setResource(@Nullable GifDrawable resource) {
             imageView.setImageDrawable(resource);
         }
     });
```

Comment: I'm reading in  https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource 
.
"A bitmap graphic file (.png, .jpg, or .gif). Creates a BitmapDrawable."
.
I just need only the bitmap object for use it.

Answer (score 0):

Glide has the ability to load gif animations to an Imageview. If you have glide 4+ just change from `asBitmap()` to `asGif()`. But keep on mind that at GIF animation consumes quite a lot of memory. So use it wisely.

Comment: asGif() return only GifDrawable ?
I can not use it.